# Exception when filtering system.parts (ClickHouse) by partition

Tags: sql, http, filter, clickhouse

I tried to execute drop partitions in table `internet_users`
With query with filter

```
SELECT DISTINCT partition  
FROM system.parts 
WHERE database='users' and table='internet_users' and 
partition= '\'d2019-10-11\''
```

Also I tried

```
partition= 'd2019-10-11'
partition= toString('d2019-10-11')
```

Filtering doesn’t work or there was an exception

```
DB::Exception: Missing columns: 'd2019' while processing query: '(d2019 - 10) - 11', required columns: 'd2019', source columns: '_dummy' (version 19.15.2.2 (official build))
```

Help me pls write successfully working filter that ClickHouse read filter condition as String,  not as expression. I cant recreate the table.

I send the request as a URL 'query' parameter and the option with 
`partition= '\'d2019-10-11\''` successfully works in 1.1.54385 version.

Also the partition columns in system.parts in in 1.1.54385 version contains 'd2019-10-11' among system.parts in in 19.15.2.2 version contains d2019-10-11, the same without quotes.

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE users.internet_users

CREATE TABLE users.internet_users (`type` Nullable(String), `report_type_date` String) 
ENGINE = MergeTree 
PARTITION BY report_type_date ORDER BY oper_date SETTINGS index_granularity = 8192
```

Comment: Column `partition` is of type `String`. So there's no reason why `partition='d2019-10-11'` should not work. Maybe upgrading CH version might help.

Comment: @ simPod, I use the last version 19.15.2.2

Comment: oh I see, it's latest. Nvm

Comment: it's known issue https://github.com/ClickHouse/ClickHouse/issues/4735 because of incompatible change a year ago https://github.com/ClickHouse/ClickHouse/pull/3652

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you need report_type_date as  String ? It's really weird.

I could not reproduce the issue

```
ClickHouse client version 19.15.2.2 (official build).
Connecting to localhost:9000 as user default.
Connected to ClickHouse server version 19.15.2 revision 54426.

CREATE TABLE internet_users (`type` Nullable(String), `report_type_date` String)  
ENGINE = MergeTree  PARTITION BY report_type_date ORDER BY tuple();

insert into internet_users values ('x', 'd2019-10-11');

SELECT
    partition,
    name,
    partition_id
FROM system.parts
WHERE active AND (table = 'internet_users') AND (partition = 'd2019-10-11')

┌─partition───┬─name───────────────────────────────────┬─partition_id─────────────────────┐
│ d2019-10-11 │ 1d3f8b04c0f3f7654e4391f6c7b73352_1_1_0 │ 1d3f8b04c0f3f7654e4391f6c7b73352 │
└─────────────┴────────────────────────────────────────┴──────────────────────────────────┘
```

partition is a String , you don't need to screen quotes.

```
curl -q 'http://localhost:8123/?query=SELECT%20partition%20FROM%20system.parts%20WHERE%20active%20AND%20(table%20%3D%20%27internet_users%27)%20AND%20(partition%20%3D%20%27d2019-10-11%27)'
d2019-10-11
```

Comment: Thank you for response. Just have updated the questions. I use the http request and URL parameter with querry.

Comment: I've updated my answer with curl -q 'http://localhost:8123/?query=SE
Don't see a problem as well.